# Find a value in next td tag with bs4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Any way to pick the value `6.543` (ignoring `<b>`), belonging to next `<td>` after `Hello Friend` ?

```
 <tr>
  <td align="right" colspan="4">
   Hey Hello Friend
  </td>
  <td align="right">
   2.123
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td align="right" colspan="4">
   <b>
    Hello Friend 
    <sup>
     3
    </sup>
   </b>
  </td>
  <td align="right">
   <b>
    6.543
   </b>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Note there is 'Hey Hello Friend' and 'Hello Friend '.

Using `soup.find("td", text=re.compile("Hello Friend ")).find_next_sibling("td")` does not work. It returns `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next_sibling'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method using only CSS selectors:

```py
print(soup.select_one('td:has(b:-soup-contains("Hello Friend")) + td').get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
6.543
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is looking for the element containing that text (in this case, a `b` tag) **sibling**: that `<b>` tag has no `<td>` sibling. What you need is:

```
soup.find("b", text=re.compile("Hello Friend")).find_next("td")
```

See BeautifulSoup documentation [here](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: I like the simplicity of your syntax but I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'`. I suspect it is because of `<sup>`.